# Prove that the size of any set $A$ is smaller than the size of its powerset $P(A)$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Prove that the size of any nonempty set $A$ is smaller than its powerset $P(A)$, i.e. $|A| < |P(A)|$. My approach to this problem is as follows.

First I consider all sets whose size is less than two, $|A| < 2$. Let $|A| = 1$, i.e. the case where $A$ has only one element $a \in A$. Then, the powerset of $A$, $P(A)$, contains two elements, the empty set and the single element $a$, i.e. $\{ \emptyset, a \}$. In this case $|A| = 1 < 2 = P(A)$ and the claim holds.

Now I consider all sets whose size is at least two, $|A| \geq 2$. Let $|A| \geq 2$. According to the definition of the powerset $P(A)$ of $A$, the powerset contains all elements of $A$, so $|A| \leq |P(A)|$. I search for elements in $P(A)$ not in $A$. I observe that the set $A$ is itself a subset of $A$ and so is an element of $P(A)$. This element is not in $A$ and so $|A| < |P(A)|$. So I conclude that for any set whose size is at least two I find an element in the powerset which is not present in $A$. And so we conclude that the size of any set $A$ is smaller than the size of its powerset. And so the claim holds in general.

The proof can be simplified by noting that for any set $A$ the empty set $\emptyset$ is a member of the powerset $P(A)$, but not of $A$, i.e. $\emptyset \notin A$, and since each element in $A$ is also in the powerset the size of the powerset $P(A)$ is at least one greater than the size of $A$, i.e. $|A| + 1 \leq |P(A)|$ which imples $|A| < P(A)$, and so the claim holds.

Now it should be stated that the proof relies on the assumption that $A$ contains no other sets as elements, e.g. the empty set.

So to summarize I use the fact that all elements in $A$ are also in $P(A)$ and $P(A)$ contains elements not in $A$ so its size is strictly greater than $A$.

Are there any flaws in the approaches I followed? And what could possible alternative approaches be?

Comment: It is not true that for any set $A$ the empty set is not a member of the set $A$. For example, $\emptyset\in\{\emptyset\}=A$.

Comment: "the powerset contains all elements of A": no. E.g. if $A=\{1,2\}$ then the elements of $P(A)$ are $\varnothing,\{1\},\{2\},A.$ None of them is equal to $1$ for instance.

Comment: Strictly speaking, for each element of $A$, the power set of $A$ contains a singleton set which contains this element of $A$. The power set itself generally does not contain the element of $A$.

Comment: I'm confused, aren't all elements of a set $A$ also elements of the powerset of $A$?

Comment: The power set is the set of subsets of $A$. If an element of $A$ is not a subset of $A$, then it is not an element of the power set.

Comment: " This element is not in A and so |A|<|P(A)|", or "|A|+1≤|P(A)|
 which imples |A|<P(A)": no. For infinite sets, $X\subsetneq Y$ does not imply $|X|<|Y|.$ And if you only deal with finite sets, no need for all this: just check that $n<2^n.$

Comment: So for each element of $A$ the powerset of $A$ contains a singleton set which contains this element. So from this I could conclude that the size of the powerset $P(A)$ is at least the size of the set $A$? Since there are additional elements in the powerset then the size of the powerset is strictly greater than the size of $A$?

Comment: I thought that a set $A$ could not be put into one-to-one correspondence with its powerset, regardless of the size. So even for infinite sets $|A| < |P(A)|$.

Comment: Even once you were to more formally and more correctly say what you hope you are saying, this merely shows that this *particular* choice of a function $A\to \mathcal{P}(A)$ is not surjective.  This does not yet prove that *every* choice of a function $A\to \mathcal{P}(A)$ is not surjective.  There is still a great deal of work left to be done.

Comment: Yes, even for infinite sets |A|<P(A), but your proof is not salvageable. Better look for instance at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem#Proof

Comment: Your attempt at a proof can be paraphrased as "*I can exhibit an injective function which maps elements of $A$ to $B$ which is not surjective since I can point to elements in $B$ who are not mapped to by any element of $A$, therefore $|A|<|B|$*" where here you have $B=\mathcal{P}(A)$... but this same line of logic would have supposedly also worked for if $A=\Bbb N$ and $B=\Bbb Z$, using the identity map $f(x)=x$ and noting that $-1$ is not mapped to.  Despite this, $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb Z$ **famously** have the same cardinality.  All you showed was that $|A|\leq |B|$, but not yet that $|A|<|B|$.

Comment: @JMoravitz This is true, the reasoning I used would conclude that the set of natural numbers and integers would be of different size... I'm having some trouble with this whole infinity business.

Comment: Try finding an injection from A to it's Powerset. ( This establishes that A is no bigger, cardinality-wise than it's Powerset) Then, try a proof by contradiction to show that there is no bijection from a set to it's Powerset. This establishes that a set is not equal, cardinality-wise to it's Powerset. Then conclude that a set must have  a stricly smaller cardinality than it's Powerset.

Comment: @MichaelCarey All you need to show is that no map from $A$ to its power set can be surjective.

Comment: ^ That's true. I gave a more roundabout hint because I thought it might be more instructive to go that route. This classical Theorem is close to my heart, and I wanted the OP to really play with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Claim:**  Let $f: A \to \mathscr P(A)$ be a map.  Then $f$ is not surjective.  Note that the claim proves that $\vert A \vert \lt \vert \mathscr P(A) \vert$ even for infinite $A$.

**Proof:**  Define $B=\{ x \in A \mid x \notin f(x) \} \in \mathscr P(A)$.  **Claim:**  $B \notin f(A)$.  If, contrary to the Claim, $B=f(y)$ for some $y \in A$, then $y \in B \Rightarrow y \notin f(y)=B$ by the definition of $B$.  That contradiction shows that $y \in f(y)$ is not possible.  On the other hand, $y \notin f(y)\Rightarrow y \in B=f(y)$, again by the definition of $B$.  That contradiction shows $y \notin f(y)$ is not possible.

If $y$ exists, however, it must be the case that either $y \in B$ or $y \notin B$, and we have now shown that neither of these alternatives is possible.  Our initial assumption was that $\exists y~(f(y)=B)$.  This assumption must therefore be false, so $f$ cannot be surjective.

Comment: Let me see if I understand this right. Let $B$ be as you defined and let $f$ be surjective. Then, there exists some $y \in A$ such that $f(y) = B$ since $B$ is an element of $P(A)$ and since $f$ is surjective so a mapping from some $y \in A$ to $B \in P(A)$ must exist. Now let $y \in B$ then $y \in f(y)$ which implies $y \notin B$ according to the definition of $B$. A contradiction. Now let $y \notin B$ then $y \notin f(y)$ and so this implies $y \in B$. Another contradiction. So $f$ is not surjective. Am I understanding this correctly? I tried writing out your proof in words.

Comment: I've accepted the answer as I feel I'm starting to understand your proof.

Comment: @prcssngnr Just note that $f$ has to come before $B$ because I use $f$ in the definition of $B$.  But yes, I think you understand the reasoning.